# POST request to ruby on rails server fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, cordova, post

I'm building a rails application with some apis for the mobile application.

The problem is that all the POST requests do not work.

Here's how I call them (from the phonegap application):

```
 72                 $.ajax({
 73                     url: 'http://www.my-website.com:port/api/login',
 74                     type: 'POST',
 75                     dataType: 'json',
 76                     data:{"email":"my-email",
 77                         "password":"my-password"},
 78                     success: function(data){
 79                         alert(data);
 80                     },
 81                     error: function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
 82                         alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
 83                     }
 84                 });
```

Here's the server log:

```
Started POST "/api/login" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-04-03 10:58:51 +0000
Processing by ApiController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"\"my-email.com\"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

JSON::ParserError (A JSON text must at least contain two octets!):
  app/controllers/api_controller.rb:71:in `parse_request'
```

Here's where I get the error in the api controller:

```
before_filter :parse_request
...
  def parse_request
      @json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  end
```

Comment: No.. Problem is the **syntax** you applied.. Write it `data: { email: "my-email",..}`

Comment: Go straight down to the examples of the [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).. and see the syntax of `JSON` datatypes..

Comment: I tried without the "" but it did not work.
The strange thing is that if I send the request through the postman plugin for chrome I receive the correct data!

Comment: Answers should be answers, not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changing the ajax request code to this:

```
 69             var dt={
 70                 "email":"my-email",
 71                 "password":"my-password"
 72                 }
 73
 74             $('#submit').click(function(){
 75                 //localStorage['id'] = 10;
 76                 //if (localStorage != null)
 77                 //    window.location='index-logged.html';
 78                 $.ajax({
 79                     url: 'http://www.my-website.com/api/login',
 80                     type: 'POST',
 81                     data: JSON.stringify(dt),
 82                     cache: false,
 83                     success: function(data){
 84                         alert(data);
 85                     },
 86                     error: function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
 87                         alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])'
 88                     }
 89                 });
 90             });
```